# How do I update a spinner list from another class/view?

Tags: android

I have a spinner on my main view and I want to add and remove items from it's array from another view. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Boyd

Comment: Do you mean Activities and not views?  Because if everything is in the same activity it's a trivial operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding/removing items in another Activity (making that assumption here), then however you're handling data should update the spinner in the spinner's activity's onCreate or onResume (which would probably happen anyways).

And like BrennaSoft said in the comment, if it's happening in the same activity, then there should be no problem modifying the array the spinner is using for data